# Hide simple product when in configurable

Tags: magento2, catalog, search, catalogsearch

Hide all simple products from Catalog or Search results that are added in the configurable products?

Comment: Set the configuration products as "invisible individually" and only the parent as visibility "Catalog/search"

Comment: It is not working @AlanZavagli

Answer (score 0):

In the General tab of the simple products, set Visibility to Not Visible Individually. This will hide them from the front-end, but keep them enabled for use with the configurable products.

This can also be done programmatically if that's how you're creating the products:

> $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)